# Pipeline Schedule not working on Github-Action

Tags: github-actions, pipeline

Team, I was unable to adjust this condition. It is possible to save the yaml but it does not trigger the schedule. Can anyone help me identify the error?

************ my yaml ******************

```
name: Newman Tests by Postman.

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 15 * * 1,2,3,4,5'     **-- my problem is here**
    
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  newman:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
        # 1 - Step - Install dependences.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm install -g newman | 
             npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev |
             npm install -g newman-reporter-allure 

      # 2 -Step - Run the POSTMAN collection
      - name: Step 2 - Run POSTMAN collection
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
             newman run florida_release_notes.postman_collection.json -e Env-1fpay-test.postman_environment.json -r allure
        
      - name: mostra as pastas
        run: dir
      - name:  Step 3 - Collect Allure files and generate allure-report folder
        run: |
          allure generate ./allure-results -o allure-report/
      - name:  Step 4 - Publishing Allure artifact to GitHub Actions
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: allure-report
          path: allure-report
```

[image]

Comment: The time is in UTC, did you expect it to run in some other timezone perhaps? The expression looks correct.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks  the line is selected, I have already adjusted the position and the scheduling does not work

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work". The blue curly is to indicate there is a tooltip. You could try `0 15 * * 1-5` or `0 15 * * MON-FRI` instead...

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you, I committed the file, let's see if the schedule will work

Comment: What was the tooltip? And if you hadn't committed the file yet, did you assume "blue squiggly line" implies "doesn't work"?

Comment: @BenjaminW.    The pipeline didn't run, I thought it was due to the position of the line in the yaml file.  
I'll wait now for it to be fired at 1 pm, time here in Brazil

Comment: 3 pm UTC is 12 pm in Brazil, no?

Comment: @BenjaminW. hummm really, tks  .. 
taking advantage of your great help, is it possible to send a hyperlink in the body of the email after the execution of the pipeline?

Comment: I don't think the email can be customized, but you could trigger another workflow on the [`workflow_run` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) and do whatever you want in there.

Comment: @BenjaminW.
Do you have a manual that explains this?

Comment: The link in my comment goes to the documentation of the event, did you mean that?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Tks, friend my schedule doesn't start, I don't know what happens. I changed to: on:
  schedule:
  - cron: '0 11 * * MON-FRI'

Comment: I don't think weekday shortnames are understood by actions. Notice that the start times for scheduled jobs aren't exact, more of a best effort estimate.

Comment: According to the docs each of these syntaxes should work. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule. I just tried this: `schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * 1-5'` which works, though it took 8 minutes for it to trigger not 5.